# Is there a way to manually trigger WordPress' heartbeat

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

I have written something that hook into WordPress' heartbeat via the `heartbeat-send` JS event.
However, to test things I am doing a lot of sitting around and waiting.

I've tried to run `jQuery(document).trigger("heartbeat-send");` from the console with no luck.
I'm unsure of how to trigger the heartbeat at any time, or if it's even possible :)

Answer (score 1):

Was just looking for this myself and came across this answer on another site to manually trigger the heartbeat:

```
wp.heartbeat.connectNow();
```

Comment: It should be selected as a correct answer, you saved my day thank you

Answer (score -1):

Please refer this below link its help you

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/heartbeat-api/

```
jQuery(document).on('heartbeat-tick', function(event, data) {
    // Check for our data, and use it.
    if (!data.myplugin_customfield_hashed) {
        return;
    }
    alert('The hash is ' + data.myplugin_customfield_hashed);
});
```

Comment: Is the `tick` not the receiving event?  How do you force the heartbeat to happen outside of the interval set by WordPress?  A lame example would be: I wanted to trigger the heartbeat to run when I clicked a button.  How would you do that?  Is it even possible?